# Understanding classical massive real scalar $\phi^4$ Callan-Symanzik equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, renormalization, classical-field-theory

Considering classical massive real scalar field theory by the action:

$S[\phi] = \frac{1}{2}\int d^4x[\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-m^2\phi^2-\frac{g}{12}\phi^4]  $

we assume the theory is invariant to scale invariance so $\phi(x) \to \phi'(x)$
for any scale $\lambda$: $\phi(x)=\phi'(x)=\lambda\phi(\lambda x)$

to ensure that the action will be invariant we find that specificlly the mass term have a problem:
$S_{mass}[\phi']=-\frac{1}{2}m^2\int d^4x \phi'^2(x)=-\frac{1}{2}m^2\lambda^2\int d^4x \phi^2(\lambda x)$ (if we define new variable as massless part $y=\lambda x $) we find that:
$S_{mass}[\phi']=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{m^2}{\lambda^2}\int d^4y \phi^2(y)\ne-\frac{1}{2}m^2\int d^4y \phi^2(y)=S_{mass}[\phi]$

So we have to add another transformation law to the mass so the theory would be scale invariant: $m\to m'$ when $m'=\lambda m$

now considering correlator: $G_m(x_1,....,x_n)=<T[\phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n)]>_m=\int\mathcal D\phi \cdot e^{iS[\phi]}\phi(x_1)...\phi(x^n)$

So under scale invariance we should get:
$<T[\phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n)]>_m=<T[\phi'(x_1)...\phi'(x_n)]>_{m'}=\lambda^n<T[\phi(\lambda x_1)...\phi(\lambda x_n)]>_{\lambda m}$

so: $G_m(x_1,...,x_n)=\lambda^n G_{\lambda m}(\lambda x_1,...,\lambda x_n)$

in addition in the "classical" case the coupling $g$ not flowing and we don`t add renormalization to the fields.

We will get the Callan-Symanzik equation by demanding that for Infinitesimal scale transformation of the correlator: $G\to G+\delta G$ we have: $\delta G=0$

To get $\delta G$ we should know how the field transform and how the mass transform infinitesimally under scale transformation, to do so I take $\lambda \to 1+\epsilon$ when $\epsilon<<1$ (because for $\lambda =1$ we receiving the original scalar field and the original mass) and we got:
$\phi'(x)\approx (1+\epsilon)(\phi(x+\epsilon x)) \approx (1+\epsilon)(\phi(x)+\epsilon x \frac{d\phi}{dx})\approx \phi(x)+\epsilon(\phi(x)+x \frac{d\phi}{dx})$
$m'\approx (1+\epsilon)m = m+ \epsilon m$

and so: $\delta \phi=\phi+x \frac{d\phi}{dx}, \delta m = m$

We conclude:

$$\delta G= \sum_{i=1}^n(1+x_i\frac{d}{dx_i})G_m(x_1,...,x_n)=(n+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\frac{d}{dx_i})G_m(x_1,...,x_n)=0$$
But I know the answer have to include the mass transformation such that:
$$\delta G=(n+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\frac{d}{dx_i}-m\frac{d}{dm})G_m(x_1,...,x_n)=0$$
how to show it when I know that the correlator not depend explicitly in the mass (because the action invariant in the path integral)?

Comment: Massive theories are not scale invariant and their correlators depend on the mass.

Comment: In which way the correlator depend on mass explicitly?

Comment: $\frac{1}{p^2 + m^2}$ is the Fourier transform of a two-point correlator which depends on mass explicitly.